# ListView doesn't show first textview item

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a listview, every row contains an imageview and two text views. The image and the second textview is shown but the first textview is blank...Can't figure out what's wrong...I can't wrap my head around custom list adapters...I have read http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf to.

My data is loaded correctly to the arraylist.
My code:

```
private class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Szam> {

        private ArrayList<Szam> items;

        public SongAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,     ArrayList<Szam> items) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                this.items = items;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                }
                Szam o = items.get(position);
                if (o != null) {
                        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
                        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
                        if (tt != null) {
                              tt.setText(o.getArtist());                            }
                        if(bt != null){
                              bt.setText(o.getTitle());
                        }
                }
                return v;
        }
```

And my xml layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="6dip">

<TextView android:id="@+id/secondLine" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/firstLine" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="My Application" />
<ImageView android:layout_marginRight="6dip" android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:src="@drawable/play" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The corrected layout is:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/secondLine1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"

    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/firstLine1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"

    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:text="My Application" />

<ImageView android:layout_marginRight="6dip" android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:src="@drawable/play" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use LinearLayouts?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView android:layout_marginRight="6dip" android:id="@+id/icon" android:src="@drawable/play" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="My Application" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/firstLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
        <TextView android:singleLine="true" android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee" android:id="@+id/secondLine" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I rewrote my row layout to the code you gave me, now my application gives me an error when calling v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

Comment: I've changed the layout to match your params. Please, take a look

Comment: Thanks i had the same problem your answer is very valueable to me ...thanks a lot

Comment: @AlparTorok can you tell us what is issue becaus currently im facing the same issue.